# Get max,min of offset from kafka dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Below is how I'm reading data from kafka.

```
 val inputDf = spark.readStream
 .format("kafka")
 .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
 .option("subscribe", topic)
 .option("startingOffsets", """{"topic1":{"1":-1}}""")
 .load()

 val df = inputDf.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)","CAST(topic AS STRING)","CAST (partition AS INT)","CAST (offset AS INT)","CAST (timestamp AS STRING)")
```

How can I get the max & min offsets and timestamp from above dataframe? I want to save it to some external source for future reference.I cannot use 'agg' function as i'm writing same dataframe to writestream(as shown below)

```
 val kafkaOutput = df.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("path", "/warehouse/download/data1")
  .format("console")
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_loc)
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade your Spark version to 2.4.0 you will be able to solve this issue.

In Spark 2.4.0, you have spark foreachbatch api through which you can write the same DataFrame to multiple sinks.

Spark.writestream.foreachbatch((batchDF, batchId) => some_fun(batchDF)).start()

some_fun(batchDF): { persist the DF & perform the aggregation}